# How to convert object into array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm converting json object to an array. The data I get is like below. I have try google but not found the answer. How to solve this issue from data below

```
[{"january":"0.00","february":"0.00","mac":"1271.00","april":"5.00","may":"0.00","june":"0.00","july":"0.00","august":"0.00","september":"0.00","october":"0.00","november":"0.00","december":"0.00"}]
```

into this

```
$scope.data = [
        [0.00, 0.00, 1271.00, 5.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
      ];
```

in file.html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
         <i class="icon-graph icon-bg"></i>Bar Chart
    </div>
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="graph" chart-labels="labels"></canvas>

</div>
```

in file.js

```
$http.get(commonData.apiURL + 'dashboard/countDataGraph.php')
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.graph = data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errorMessage = "Couldn't load the list of Orders, error # " + status;
            console.log("error");
    });
```

Comment: Your input data is just an array with a unique object or it can have multiple objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Object properties in JavaScript are unordered**, so solutions that use `Object.values()` can offer no guarantees about the resulting array being correctly ordered.

You have to get the individual values out in the right order, and construct a new array out of them. Pre-defining an array of months, combined with a `map()` operation will do the trick:

```js
const months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december'];
const data = [{"january":"0.00","february":"0.00","march":"1271.00","april":"5.00","may":"0.00","june":"0.00","july":"0.00","august":"0.00","september":"0.00","october":"0.00","november":"0.00","december":"0.00"}];

const result = data.map(v => months.map(m => v[m]));
       
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Do you know if `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` iterates the object in order? I have read it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties), but i'm still confused if some method can traverse or not an object in order of keys creation.

Comment: @Shidersz If have given up trying to figure it out. There are all kinds of edge cases and older browsers will not follow the ECMAScript 2015/2016. If I need to rely on order, I use a `Map`.

Comment: When I use code that having    => my controller will be error. How to fix that?

Comment: `data.map(function(v) { return months.map(function(m)  { return v[m]; })});` But seriously, if you want to support browsers that old, you should look into BabelJS or something similar to transpile.

Comment: okay thanks @RobbyCornelissen . Its working fine now! Really appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `Object.values`

```
Object.values(o) // Returns an array of values.
```

```js
let obj = [{"january":"0.00","february":"0.00","mac":"1271.00","april":"5.00","may":"0.00","june":"0.00","july":"0.00","august":"0.00","september":"0.00","october":"0.00","november":"0.00","december":"0.00"}];
let values = obj.map(Object.values);
console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer completely ignores the fact that object properties in JavaScript are unordered. You might get your results back in the correct order, you might not. It's completely dependent on the JavaScript engine implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map()` and `Object.values`

```js
const arr = [{"january":"0.00","february":"0.00","mac":"1271.00","april":"5.00","may":"0.00","june":"0.00","july":"0.00","august":"0.00","september":"0.00","october":"0.00","november":"0.00","december":"0.00"}]

const res = arr.map(x => Object.values(x));

console.log(res);
```